# create a css notification pop up

Tags: css

I want to create a popup notification, 
I have a div with initial top -200px

```
#onthefly-main {
  height: 190px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -200px;
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5;
  transition: all 0.5;
```

I also have defined a class with top: 20px;

```
#onthefly-main.visible {
    top: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5;
    transition: all 0.5;
}

var onClick = function() {
  document.getElementById('onthefly-main').classList.add('visible');

};
```

This makes the div visible but the transition is not been displayed as animation.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/2638/

Comment: The duration unit value must be terminated with an "s" for "seconds", e.g: `transition: all 0.5s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I add `transition: all ease 0.5s` to your main ID. Maybe just missing the transition animation style (ease) and the unit for time (0.5s) is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the time unit after your transition delay value.

Change this: `-webkit-transition: top 0.5;`

to this: `-webkit-transition: top 0.5s;`